# How to Back into Activity when click button type submit in WebView

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem to back into previous Activity after fill form and click button type submit in My WebView App.

Code [Web] :

```
<form action="mysite.com/sell.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "hidden" name = "sell">
    <input type = "text" name = "name">
    <input type = "number" name = "phone">
    <button type = "submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Code [PHP] sell.php

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 //Getting values
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];


 //Creating an sql query
 $sql = "INSERT INTO sell (name,phone) VALUES ('$name','$phone')";

 //Importing our db connection script
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 //Executing query to database
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo 'success';
 }else{
 echo 'failure';
 }

 //Closing the database 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

XML [WebView]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

WebView Activity

```
public class MyWebView extends AppCompatActivity{
WebView view;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.view_web_my);

            String url = "mysite.com/";

            view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            view.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

how can i back to previous Activity after click button "Save" ?

Comment: we have nothing to do with action of the form thats where you send data when its submitted  ,post your web View related code and xml

Comment: @Charuka i use php native in my web aplication to handle form action

Comment: Okay seems i got your question you have a button called submit in your WEB VIew and you want to return back to mobile app when it is pressed ? Is that your requirement ! read and answer properly

Comment: Also post your code in activity!